# ASP.NET databound listbox delete item from button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET webpage. I have a listbox that is databound. It has a DeleteCommand and I linked up DeleteParameter to the selected value of the listbox. I also have a button that I want to trigger the delete command of the listbox SqlDataSource.

How do I hook up the button to cause the delete command to execute for the databound list box's SqlDataSource?

Comment: I went ahead and deleted my post, because it would just be confusing to future visitors =)  Glad you got a solution to your problem, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqlDataSource` has a `Delete()` method.  You can have your delete button call this method when it is clicked:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.Delete();
}
```

---

`SqlDataSource.Delete` according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.aspx):

> Performs a delete operation using the DeleteCommand SQL string and any
>   parameters that are in the DeleteParameters collection.